# How can I send foreign characters with YUI io (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest, yui, decode

I'm using YUI io to post data to my server. I have some problems sending foreign characters like æ ø å.

First case: a form is posted to the server

```
Y.io(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        id: 'myform',
        useDisabled: true
    }
});
```

This will post the content of the form to the server. If I have a field named "test1" containing "æøå", then on the server I'll see REQUEST_CONTENT="test1=%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5". This can be easily decode with a urldecode function, NO PROBLEM, but...

Second case: data is posted this way:

```
Y.io(uri, {
    data   : '{"test1":"æøå"}'),
    method : "POST"
});
```

Now I see this on the server REQUEST_CONTENT="{"test1":"├ª├©├Ñ"}". How can I decode that? And why is it send like that?

I know I can use encodeURIComponent() to encode the string before sending it. But the io request is actually part of a Model Sync operation, so I'm not calling io directly. I'm doing something like this:

```
Y.User = Y.Base.create('user', Y.Model, [Y.ModelSync.REST], {....});
var user = new Y.User();
user.set('test1', 'æøå');
user.save();
```

So it doesn't make sense to encode/decode everytime I set/read the attribute.

Also I have tried to set charset=utf-8 in the request header, but that didn't change anything.

EDIT

I have done some more debugging in chrome and the request is created with this line of code:

```
transaction.c.send(data);
```

transaction.c is the xmlhttprequest and (using chrome debugger) I can see the data is "{"test1":"æøå"}"
When the above line of code is executed, a pending network entry is shown (under the network tab in chrome debugger). Request payload displays {"test1":"├ª├©├Ñ"}
Headers are:

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelSync.REST` has a `serialize` method that decides how the data in the model is turned into a string before passing it to Y.io. By default it uses `JSON.stringify()` which returns what you're seeing. You can decode it in the server using JSON. By your mention of `urldecode` I guess you're using PHP in the server. In that case you can use `json_decode` which will give you an associative array. If I'm not mistaken (I haven't used PHP in a while), it should go something like this:

```
$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);

/*
array(1) {
  ["test1"] => "æøå"
}
*/
```

Another option would be for you to override the `serialize` method in your `User` model. `serialize` is a method used by `ModelSync.REST` to turn the data into a string before sending it through IO. You can replace it with a method that turns the data in the model into a regular query string using [the querystring module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/QueryString.html):

```
Y.User = Y.Base.create('user', Y.Model, [Y.ModelSync.REST], {
  serialize: function () {
    return Y.QueryString.stringify(this.toJSON());
  }
});
```

Finally, `ModelSync.REST` assumes you'll be using JSON so you need to delete the default header so that IO uses plain text. You should add this at some point in your code:

```
delete Y.ModelSync.REST.HTTP_HEADERS['Content-Type'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @juandopazo. Unfortunately I don't use php but a Domino server. So I don't have the json_decode available. I have looked a little more into the second option. But I'm not able to make any sense of it. Using stringify like this:     Y.log(Y.JSON.stringify(Y.JSON.parse('{"test1":"æøå"}'))); Will not encode the characters... Also see my edit in the question

Comment: Ugh! Domino! Been there. I updated my answer trying to be more clear on what `serialize` does.

Comment: Serialize seems like a good place to do some work. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the help.